# How can I modify static HTML file served by Nginx?

Tags: nginx, static-files

I want to modify static HTML file served by Nginx, i.e. substitute "FOO" for "BAR" (for example, to inject user's IP address in javascript variable).

I don't want to setup full PHP/Python etc. app for this simple task.

Is it possible with Nginx only?

Comment: You can try [`ngx_http_sub_module`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_sub_module.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with [ngx_http_sub_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_sub_module.html).